# What is 'gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper' docker image used for?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My overall goal is to install a **self-hosted** [gitlab-runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/) that is restricted **to use prepared docker images from my own docker registry only**.

For that I have a system.d configuration that looks like:

*/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/allow-private-registry-only.conf*

```
BLOCK_REGISTRY='--block-registry=all'
ADD_REGISTRY='--add-registry=my.private.registry:8080'
```

By this, `docker pull` is allowed to pull images from `my.private.registry/` only.

After I had managed to get this working, I wanted to clean up my local registry and remove old `docker images`. It was during that process when I stumbled over a docker image named `gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper` which presumably is some component used by the [gitlab-runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/) itself and presumably has been pulled from `docker.io`.

Now I'm wondering if it is even possible/advisable to block images from `docker.io` when using a [gitlab-runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/)?

Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`gitlab-runner-helper` image is used by GitLab Runner [to handle Git, artifacts, and cache operations](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#helper-image) for `docker`, `docker+machine` or `kubernetes` executors.

As you prefer pulling an image from a private registry, you can [override the helper image](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#override-the-helper-image). Your configuration could be :

```
[[runners]]
  (...)
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    (...)
    helper_image = "my.private.registry:8080/gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:tag"
```

Please ensure the image is present on your registry or your configuration enable proxying [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/) or `registry.gitlab.com`. For this last, you need to run at least Gitlab runner version 13.7 and having enabled `FF_GITLAB_REGISTRY_HELPER_IMAGE` feature flag.

Answer (score 29):

I feel my sovereign duty to extend the accepted answer (it is great btw), because the word *'handle'* basically tells us not so much, it is too abstract. Let me explain the whole flow in far more details:

1. When the build is about to begin, gitlab-runner creates a docker volume (you can observe it with **docker volume ls** if you want). This volume will server as a storage for caches and artifacts that you are using during the build.
2. The second thing - You will have at least 2 containers involved in each stage: gitlab-runner-helper, container and the container created from the image you specified (in .gitlab-ci.yml or in config.toml). What **gitlab-runner-helper** container does it, essentially, just cloning the remote git repository (that you are building) in the aforementioned docker volume along with caches and artifacts.

It can do it becuase within gitlab-runner-helper image itself are 2 important utilities: **git** (obviously - to clone the repo) and **gitlab-runner-helper** binary (this utility can pull and push artifacts, caches)

3. The **gitlab-runner-helper** container starts before each stage for a couple of seconds, to pull artifacts and caches, and then terminates. After that the container, created from image that you specified will be launched, ant it will also have this volume (from step 1) attached - this is how it receives artifacts btw.

The rest of the details about the registry from where **gitlab-runner-helper** get pulled are described by @Nicolas pretty well. I append this comment just for someone, who, perhaps, want to know what exactly means this sneaky '*handle*' word.

Hope it helps, have a nice day, my friend!

Comment: Thank you for the extra details. Maybe could also add a link to gitlab docs where all this is documented ?

Comment: Yes, this is also what I wish to have, where did you get this information? From the source code of GitLab Runner? Anyway, this is very inspiring for us to do trouble shooting. Thanks!

Comment: This is great explanation, kudos!!